# post from php to php

Tags: php, post, client

I want to Post to PHP file, from another PHP file with PHP code, not with html forms. I don't know how to do this. i have found some info about Get but nothing about post

Comment: Are you simply attempting to share data between the files?

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question. Too unspecific, has not read the manuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use cURL:

[curl Tutorial](http://phpsense.com/php/php-curl-functions.html)

And here's a reference:

[curl Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: does it use Post method, Get method or Both methods?

Comment: you can send any http request with curl